# ¿Cómo muestro el texto de una opción cuando es seleccionada en un Spinner?

Tags: java, android

Tengo dos spinners así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero hacer algo similar a esto:

Al yo seleccionar el primer spinner me muestre un mensaje diciendo por ejemplo " 12-2 seleccionada" y despúes al seleccionar el segundo spinner me diga por ejemplo "Informática empresarial seleccionada"

Lo intenté hacerlo así:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {
        sec = seccionList.get(position).getId();
        Spinner secc;
        switch (secc){
           case secc= spinnerseccion:
               Toast.makeText(
                   getApplicationContext(),
                   seccionList.get(position).getName() + " Seleccionada" ,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               break;
            case secc =spinnerseccion:
                Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    especList.get(position).getEsc() + " Seleccionada" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
       }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
```

Pero este no funciona la variable "secc" no puede ser una operación, también lo intenté con un IF...else pero necesito una variable booleana y no sé como convertir un spinner en boolean(no creo que se pueda).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad no estás haciendo referencia a tus `Spinner` de ninguna manera. Tendrías que hacer referencia a ellos mediante sus id. Algo similar a esto:

```
(Spinner) tuSpinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1Customizado);
(Spinner) tuSpinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2Customizado);
```

Y después crear el evento para detectar cuando seleccionas un valor en cada uno de ellos. Yo lo voy a hacer para el elemento `tuSpinner1` por no alargar demasiado la respuesta pero se haría de la misma manera para el elemento `tuSpinner2`.

```
tuSpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        String texto = tuSpinner1.getSelectedItem().toString(); //Recuperamos el texto del elemento seleccionado
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),texto + "Seleccionada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
       //Tu codigo aquí para cuando no cambie nada
    }

});
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono muy bien.

Answer (score 2):

Rapidamente detecto dos cosas:

- la variable secc nunca se inicializa y sera nulo.
- la forma en que implementas switch es incorrecta.

para que tu codigo funcione como lo solicitas, tendrias que comparar el View que detona la accion de seleccion contra los spinners reales, algo como esto:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) {
    if (view == spinner1){
       [...]  // <- codigo para spiner 1
    }
    else if (view == spinner2){
       [...]  // <- codigo para spiner 2
    }
}
```

Comment: En este caso podrías hacer un `switch(view)` con los distintos cases.